# Orchard - How to set current theme from recipe

Tags: orchardcms

I need to set a theme as current from an Orchard recipe.
The theme is already enabled through the command `theme activate "KrakeDefaultTheme"`.

I know that I can use the element `<Theme packageId="ThemeName" current="true" />` to download a theme from the gallery and set it as current, but I don't need to download it, it's a custom theme that I made and it's already in the Themes folder.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `theme activate` command will set your theme as the current theme. And you can execute this from your recipe using the `<command>` element

```
<Command>
    theme activate "KrakeDefaultTheme"
</Command>
```